# JS cookie по нажатию на кнопку ДА

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Помогите пожалуйста с куки.
Мне необходимо прописывать куки после нажатия на кнопку "ДА есть 18". А у меня сейчас запись в куки происходит при загрузки страницы.

То есть у меня загружается страница, сразу открывается модальное окно в котором вопрос есть ли вам 18?
При нажатие на "Да есть 18" должна происходить запись куки.

И если запись в куки есть на "Да есть 18" - модальное больше не открывать.

Вот мой код:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    //if cookie hasn't been set...
    if (document.cookie.indexOf("ModalShown=true")<0) {
        $("#myModal").modal("show");
        //Modal has been shown, now set a cookie so it never comes back
        $("#myModalClose").click(function () {
            $("#myModal").modal("hide");
        });
        document.cookie = "ModalShown=true; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT; path=/";
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    

<div class="modal fadeIn " id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content py-4 px-4">
            <div class="text-center pb-3">
                Вам есть есть 18 ?
            </div>
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-12 py-2">
                    <button class="btn btn-warning rounded-0 my-1 mobilebutton" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">Да есть 18</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-12 py-2">
                    <a href="https://yandex.ru" class="btn btn-dark rounded-0 my-1 mobilebutton">Мне нет 18</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Так же код в редакторе: https://jsfiddle.net/synapse3/kfxpwy9t/

Так же ссылка для примера работы : http://test.synapsepro.site/

Comment: Записывайте куки непосредственно когда пользователь наживает на `Да есть 18`. То есть кнопка должна иметь событие `onclick`, в котором `document.cookie = "ModalShown=true; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT; path=/";`

Comment: В вашем случае подойдёт больше запись в localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

здесь **localStorage** будет лучше

```
$(document).redy(function(){

 $(document).on('click', '#buttonYes', function(){
    localStorage.setItem('isFirstTime', 1);
    )};


var isFirst = localStorage.getItem('isFirstTime');
if (isFirst === null || isFirst === '') {
//alert('первый раз ты здесь? покажем сообщение о доступности взрослым');
// Ваш код
}
else{
//alert('не первый раз ты здесь, тебе не покажем сообщение о доступности взрослым');
// Ваш код
}
// delete localStorage.firstVisit; // чтобы удалить запись если нужно

)};
```